# Display data into to specific element using Ajax Get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to display the data into the view. I ran the developer tools and it was saying id, fullName and dob are not defined.  These are the field name from the database.  I am not sure what i am doing wrong, please correct me.  Thanks

Data

> id fullName dob 
>  101 John Doe 3/1/2015 
>  102 Mary Ann 5/8/2010

HTML

```
<div>
      <p id="txtId"></p>
      <p id="txtName"></p>
      <p id ="txtDob"></p> 
</div>
```

Javascript

current page url is http://localhost:53327/Records?customerName=DoeJohn&customerId=101

the variable "id" grasps the param from the url(which is 101) and is then pass into the ajax url: "/api/CustomerInfoApi" + id,

```
var id = location.search.split('customerId=')[1];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/CustomerInfoApi/" + id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $("#txtId").text = data.customerId;
            $("#txtName").text = data.customerName;
            $("#txtDob").text = data.customerDob;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you check what the `data` in the success function returns?

Comment: What does `var id = location.search.split('customerId=')[1];` return? Where have you defined `fullName` and `dob`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text()` is a function. To set the text of an element you have to call it and pass the text as a parameter to it

```
        $("#txtId").text(data.customerId);
        $("#txtName").text(data.customerName);
        $("#txtDob").text(data.customerDob);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    $("#txtId").html(data.customerId);
    $("#txtName").html(data.customerName);
    $("#txtDob").html(data.customerDob);
```